# What happens if I don't close a FileInputStream in JAVA?

Tags: java, java-io, fileinputstream

Yes I know that `InputStream`s should be closed, but I wan't to know what happen if I don't and just drop the reference. Will the gc close it or it will hold the resource forever?

Comment: finalize() close it, I found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33275951/1386911

Comment: The answers here pretty much sum it up (why you need to close a FileInputStream). Especially the answer by chrylis (the last one) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541513/why-is-it-good-to-close-an-inputstream

Comment: Actually my question was: what happens. And I found the answer in FileInputStream's code, in finallise() method it is closed. Actually this answers a similar bug that presented in a system for years without causing a problem, this why I wanted to know how it has been survived: the gc closed the streams.

Comment: What happens? The file handle is held until the stream is GC'd. That may happen immediately, later, or never. In short, don't rely upon it happening.

Comment: Yes that answers how a system can survive this kind of leaks, that is good to know, such bugs can be hidden for long time.